# How to prevent bool to int conversion in constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following class, as close as possible to my production code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct M {

    M(std::string a, std::string b, T value = T(), const bool ready = false) : m_value{value}, m_ready{ ready } {}

    T m_value;
    bool m_ready;

};

auto main() -> int {
    {
        M<int> m{"a", "b"};
        std::cerr << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        M<int> m{"a", "b", true};
        std::cerr << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In the first instance the value of `m_value` is 0 as expected. In the second it's 1 since it's taking the value of bool. Is there a way to avoid the conversion?

Comment: Avoid it how? Do you want to get a compile error in this case?

Comment: And what do you expect `M<int> m{"a", "b", true};` to do with `m_value` instead?

Comment: In short: No. Are you trying to pass the `true` as the `ready` argument? Then perhaps consider *overloading* the constructor instead?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want it to behavior once you declare T as int it will assume 1.

Comment: @TheArquitect so no choice?

Comment: You declare T as int. I don't understand and true is equal to 1 then it will implicit convert it (despite bool type is in fact 'int' where a range is form 0 to 1).

Comment: @xEric_xD That would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another constructor to reject anything that isn't exactly `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct M {
    M(std::string a, std::string b, T value = T(), const bool ready = false);

    template <typename U>
    M(std::string, std::string, U, bool = false) = delete;
};
```

`M<int>("hello", hello", true)` will prefer the constructor template, which is deleted. But note that so will `M<int>("hello", "hello", '4')` as well as `M<int>("hello", "hello", 4u)`. So it's a question of really working through which precise things you want to delete.

If you literally only want to reject exactly `bool`, you can do that by constraining the template:

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, bool>, int> = 0>
M(std::string, std::string, U, bool = false) = delete;
```

Or, in C++20:

```
template <std::same_as<bool> U>
M(std::string, std::string, U, bool = false) = delete;
```

or:

```
M(std::string, std::string, std::same_as<bool> auto, bool = false) = delete;
```

Doing it this way would still allow `M<bool>` to be constructible from two `string`s and a `bool`, since the non-template constructor would still be a better match.

Comment: Another (albeit perhaps a corner-case) pro with deleting the definition of the primary template of the constructor template is that you may still define explicit specializations of it, meaning you could explicitly specialize it for a few select _different_ types, whereas outside of these specializations, `T` and `U` must be the same else the user will get a nice and telling _"Use of deleted function"_ error message. A general advice is to avoid explicitly specializing overloaded functions, but as one of the two overloaded functions (ctors) is deleted this is arguably a special case.

Answer (score 6):

You can prevent the conversion by explicitly deleting a version that directly takes `bool` as the third parameter:

```
M(std::string, std::string, bool, bool = false) = delete;
```

However, if `T` is `bool`, that's going to cause problems. So you would need to use some SFINAE gymnastics to make this definition appear only when `T` is convertible to `bool` but isn't *actually* `bool`.

Comment: This fails when T is uint64_t which is odd. Barry's response seems to work perfectly though.

Answer (score 4):

I think this works

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct M {

    template <typename U=T, typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>>>
    M(std::string a, std::string b, U value = U(), const bool ready = false) : m_value{value}, m_ready{ ready } {}

    T m_value;
    bool m_ready;

};

auto main() -> int {
    {
        M<int> m{"a", "b"};
        std::cout << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        M<int> m{"a", "b", 1};
        std::cout << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        // This does not compile
        // M<int> m{"a", "b", true};
        // std::cout << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
    {
        // This compiles
        M<bool> m{"a", "b", true};
        std::cout << m.m_value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you needn't name the `U` type template parameter in the SFINAE construct, and you could also make use of the `std::enable_if_t` helper to avoid `::type`. `U` might also be a better choice in place for `T2`, e.g.: `template <typename U=T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value>>`.

Comment: @dfri Thank you, I don't actually do much TMP but was under the impression it was uglier than necessary, that's much cleaner.